# Understanding「彼のこれまで」

Tags: grammar, meaning

I found this sentence in a character quiz from a manga.

> 彼{かれ}のこれまでをクイズ形式でおさらいしていきましょう。

What does「彼のこれまで」mean in this sentence? It means "him up till now," right? How it is different from「これまでの彼」?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「これまで」occasionally occurs as a [noun](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%AD%A4%E3%82%8C%E8%BF%84/), in addition to its functions as a [no-adjective](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%AD%A4%E3%82%8C%E8%BF%84) and [adverbial](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7). And when used as a noun, particularly when preceded by a possessive pronoun in 「～のこれまで」, it means something to the effect of "the past achievements of someone/something" or "things someone/some entity has done in the past", or simply "the past of someone/something".

I have seen in entertainment reporting things like:

> その前に○○さんのこれまでを振り返ってみよう。
> Before we go any further, let's look back on/review the past achievements of ...

when an actor/actress/singer is featured and the article writer wants to familiarize the reader with that actor/actress/singer's past movies/shows/songs.

> 彼のこれまでをクイズ形式でおさらいしていきましょう。

Since there is no context that clarifies who "彼" is and what's notable about him, it is hard to say what kinds of things in his past the conversation and the quiz are about. Given it is a manga character, roughly this line can be rendered as:

> Let's take a quiz on his past achievements/his story so far.
> Let's take a quiz to rehash what's happened in the story with him.